# boost _1_610 on vs2015 skipping 56 targets

Tags: c++, boost

I have built successfully boost_1_610 on windows 7 x64 for visual studio 2015 so I got new folder named: "stage" which contains .lib files but at the end of building I got message: "boost 1.619 vs2015 skips 56 targets".

*** I used boost in my projects and it works ok.

my only question is: does this mean something went bad or missing? 
does this affect my project or does is undermine the full functionality of library?

Comment: Usually it is due to platform or target-type decisions made during config (ex, skipping a x64 target build because the build is 32bit, or vice versa, static vs. dynamic, etc...). Check the build log for per-target skips. It should give some hint as to why a target was skipped.

Comment: @WhozCraig you mean it's a correct building?

Comment: If there were no errors, and your bits pass their unit tests, odds are, yes.

Comment: @WhozCraig: ok thanx. it works!